A novel approach for primality test
$p$ is a prime number, we have the following sum $S(p)$:
$$S(p) = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left( k^{p-1} \mod p \right) \equiv p - 1 \pmod{p}$$
Definitions
$k^{p-1} \mod p $ represents the remainder when $k^{p-1}$ is divided by $p$
$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left( k^{p-1} \mod p \right)$ is the sum of these remainders for $k$ ranging from 1 to $p-1$

The conjecture states that this sum is congruent to $p - 1$ modulo $p$ for all prime numbers $p$.

This conjecture suggests that for prime numbers, the sum of these modular powers results in a value that is congruent to $p - 1$
My question is: is it this formula already known?

It is an obvious corollary of the well-known https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Weird to include the binary mod operator when you are just writing a congruence. You can simplify this to be either: $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^{p-1}\equiv p-1\pmod p$$ or $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (k^{p-1}\bmod p)=p-1$$

See also Giuga's Conjecture.

As mentioned here (and many other places), this is an open problem known as Giuga;s conjecture,  Please delete this duplicate question.
